# How to make dymanice title in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have try near 2 hour long but could not able to change dynamically title of of view.

I am doing this:

In View:

```
  items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                itemId:'wordtitle',
                store: 'wwordstore',
                 title: '<div class=\"word-title\">{word}</div>' 

            },
```

In Model:

```
Ext.define('horror.model.testModel',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     alias: 'model.testmodel',

       config: {
           fields: [
           {
              name: 'word'
           },

           ]
     }
});
```

In store data succesfull added but could not change the title.

only

> {word}

display on title.

So, Please me so idea , how to get dynamically title.

Answer (score 0):

Drop an id config on your titlebar so you can reference it easily.

If you are using a controller add a ref in for `myTitleBar : 'titlebar[id=yourTitlebarId]'` and when you want to change the title call `getMyTitleBar().setTitle('wow');`

If you are not using controllers see [these videos](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video/mvc-part-1).

If you are still not using controllers in you event listener where you want to set the title you can use a [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).

Also rather than using html in the title config I would recommend using the built in config options and scss to manage the display of your title, otherwise you will need to include that html each time set the title: `setTitle('<div class=\"word-title\">' + myWord + '</div>'`.

Good luck, Brad